# determine the cardinality and all inverrtible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(4,x^2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I've got to determine the cardinality and all inverrtible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(4,x^2)$.
I know that in this quotient ring $4=0$ and $x^2=0$. So $x^2=4$.
The only elements would be $\{1,2,3, x,2x,3x,1+x,2+x,3+x\}$. So $9$ elements. Is that the correct presentation?

Comment: What about zero?

Comment: Including the 0, it'd be 10. So this is fine?

Comment: What is 1 + 2x equal to? Is it a unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not arriving at the correct answer. Take $q \in \mathbb{Z}[X]/(4,X^2)$. Then $q = \pi(p)$ is the image of some $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. We can always write

$$
p = a + bX + X^2h
$$

with $h \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ (possibly zero, that causes no problems).

> Hence $q = \pi(a+bX +X^2h) = \pi(a) + \pi(b)\pi(X).$ As you say, if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $\pi(a)$ is the residue modulo $4$ of $a$. Hence $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(4,X^2) = \{a+b[X]  : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_4\}.$ You can easily check that none of these are equal. Thus the quotient has $16$ elements. As for invertible elements, now that you have that presentation, $1 = (a+b[X])(c+d[X]) = ac+(ad+bc)[X]+bd[X^2] = ac + (ad+bc)[X]$ if and only if $ac = 1$ and $ad+bc = 0$. In particular, $a$ has to be either $1$ or $3$ and $a = c$. So then we need $0 = ad+bc = a(b+c)$, which happens if $b = -d$ since we have taken $a$ invertible. I'll leave you to determine all possible cases.

Comment: One doesn't need casework to determine the units. $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle 4, X^{2} \rangle$ is a local ring with unique maximal ideal $\langle 2, X \rangle/\langle 4, X^{2} \rangle$, so the set units of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle 4, X^{2} \rangle$ is precisely the complement of $\langle 2, X \rangle/\langle 4, X^{2} \rangle$.

Comment: I don't easily see which elements are on the complement of $ \langle 2,X \rangle / \langle 4,X^2 \rangle$. That said, I know only the basics of ring theory. How could one see that quotient and guess the form of its elements?